# Implementing a Time-Out function in VBA in case code gets stuck

Tags: excel, vba, thomson-reuters-eikon

I'm currently using VBA to automate pulling of large data-sets. However, it often happens that either

1. the sub simply gets stuck and does not update any more/connection breaks (application is still responsive) or
2. the application becomes totally unresponsive.

Is there a way to implement a time-out function which automatically closes the application after say 15 minutes elapse?

In other programming languages, I would have solved this using multi-threading. But not sure if something similar is feasible in VBA given that it is entirely single-threaded.

The basic algorithm I employed to automate the data looks like this:

```
Sub automateFetchData()
Dim requestTable As Workbook

Set requestTable = Workbooks.Open(requestTablePath)
Run ("'" & requestTable.Name & "'" & "!fetchData")
' This is where the application starts fetching data and occasionally gets stuck
debug.print "Data retrieval complete"


End Sub
```

For those familiar with Thomson Reuters Datastream, I am using request tables and the pre-programmed macro within the request table file to connect and fetch data from the datastream server. 
Therefore, I unfortunately do not know/understand in detail what is happening when I run:

```
Run ("'" & requestTable.Name & "'" & "!fetchData")
```

I just know that once I call it, a progress bar appears looking like this:
[image]

Which then transitions to:
[image]

If the data retrieval is successful, the progress bar disappears, output is pasted to a worksheet and the code above reaches the

```
debug.print "Data retrieval complete"
```

Statement.

If it is not successful, it just freezes with the progress bar from the second screenshot still open and running. At this point, I would want the time-out to kick-in and exit the function which called

```
Run ("'" & requestTable.Name & "'" & "!fetchData")
```

Please excuse me for being so vague in the description of the issue. I'd be glad if someone could nonetheless help me out! Always happy to share more info where I can. Cheers!

Comment: So you're opening your own workbook, and at some point your code calls `automateFetchData`. This sub then opens another workbook with it's own built-in macros, of which you're requesting the `fetchData` method to execute. Unfortunately, it's the other workbook's macro that is hanging, not yours. And even more unfortunately, VBA doesn't have any multi-threaded process calls built in. So your workbook will hand until the second workbook's code finishes. The only possible "out" I can think of is if the second workbook's code makes calls to `DoEvents` which would let you issue a break of some kind

Comment: My other (untested) idea is an external timer that would somehow figure out the second workbook process has hung and then will kill the process from the Task Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I guess it's as you said: I'll have to kill the application from outside of Excel. I tried to trace the functions which are called by the other workbook and it seems to be calling come method within a COM Interface. Unfortunately, I have no clue on how to see what gets executed within that interface ..

Comment: Did you consider using the API instead of Excel? https://developers.thomsonreuters.com/eikon-apis/datastream-web-service

Comment: @Hoenie, yes I did. Unfortunately, the API only allows downloading 10 million datapoints a month. Given the size of my sample, that would be too little, which is why I chose the method using request tables.